# Loop through range of cells to check if it is a number (any number)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to loop through a range of cells and check if the cell is a number or not. I'm aware that dates are actually numbers and I will be searching for number of dates. So let's say I want to check the range ("A2:A10") and if the cell is a number, add 1 to my datecount variable. The ISNUMBER() function seems to only be useful if you are looking for a specific number. But I'm looking for any number.

```
Sub Main()

Dim Datecount As Integer
Datecount = 0

Range("A2").Select
For Each c In Range("2:2")
    If c.Value.IsNumber() Then
        Datecount = Datecount + 1

Next

End Sub
```

The above is the most important thing I need help with. If you can help with that, great! If you can help with this next part, that would be wonderful as well. Basically, I'd like to check if the cell is a number just like above. But this time, if it isn't a number I want it to exit the loop.

```
Dim Datecount As Integer
Datecount = 0

Range("A2").Select
For Each c In Range("2:2")
    If c.Value.IsNumber() Then
        Datecount = Datecount + 1
    ElseIf
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no question in your post. What exactly is your question?

Comment: If you want to loop through the range "A2:A10", selecting "A2" isn't doing anything for you. Range ("2:2") means you are looping through every cell in row 2. You don't want to do that.

Comment: For the first part you can try `Datecount= range("2:2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants,xlnumbers).Count`. If no number exists in that range, the above returns an error so it needs to be trapped. For the second part, to avoid looping, we need to identify the first non-numeric cell (call it `aCell`) and return `aCell.column-1` (or `0`). An idea is to check the first cell of all `SpecialCells` other than xlNumbers and return the minimum column among these first cells. Not very elegant though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve your first problem, you don't need to loop at all.  A simple CountIf formula will give you what you're looking for:

```
Sub test()
Dim DateCount As Integer

DateCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("A2:A10"), ">=0")

End Sub
```

I ***think*** this will do what you're after for your second question:

```
Sub test2()
Dim LastNumberRow As Integer

If Application.Evaluate("=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISTEXT($A2:$A10),0),0),0)") = 1 Then
    LastNumberRow = 0
Else
    LastNumberRow = Application.Evaluate("=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISTEXT($A2:$A10),0),0),0)")
End If
End Sub
```

test2() will return 0 if there isn't any TEXT in the range you're checking (meaning they're all numeric cells).  Let me know if that's a problem and I'll hack my way around it...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Main()
Dim c as Range
Dim Datecount As Integer
Datecount = 0

For Each c In Range("2:2").Cells
    If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
        Datecount = Datecount + 1
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Now, I am not sure what you mean with the `IsNumber()` function. I've never heard of that. And in any case, you don't apply a function to the end of an object:

`c.Value.IsNumeric()` wil give you an error (object does not support this property or method, probably, I have not tested it)

Instead:

`IsNumeric(c.Value)`, because `c.Value` is the argument you're passing to the `IsNumeric` function.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Sub flexRange()
```

'range can be estended
    Range("b2").Select
    i = 0

```
Do Until ActiveCell = ""
    If IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Value) Then i = i + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
MsgBox "I found_" & i & "_Numeric element"

End Sub
```